# Is it possible to execute interface without abstract method?

Tags: java

When the program is executing, it executed if it comments in the interface method and nested interface method.
     So, how it's executing process.
Is it taking as a default method?

```
interface it2
{
//void m1(); with this comment program is executing so, how it is 
prosessing
interface it1
{
//void m2();with this comment also program is executing so, how it is 
prosessing
}
};
class Demo implements it2.it1
{
 void m1()
{
    System.out.println("m1 method");

}

public  void m2()
{
    System.out.println("m2 method");
}
public static void main(String[] args)

{
    Demo t= new Demo();
    t.m1();
    t.m2();
}


}
```

OUTPUT-
    m1 method
    m2 method

Comment: Your grammar is hard to understand. Please consider rephrasing your question.

Comment: You have a Demo object; you call its m1 method and that is what executes. You call its m2 method and that is what executes.

Comment: This question is pretty much unsalvageable, I think it should be closed on such grounds.

Answer (score 1):

Lets first tidy up and correct your code so that it is readable:

```
public interface It2 {
    void m1(); 

    public interface It1 {
        void m2();
    }
}

public class Demo implements It2.It1 {
    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("m1 method");
    }

    public void m2() {
        System.out.println("m2 method");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo t = new Demo();
        t.m1();
        t.m2();
    }
}
```

I think your confusion is that you think there is some relationship between the `m1` method in `It2` the `m1` method in `Demo`.

In fact there is no relationship.

The `Demo` class is implementing `It1` not `It2`.  So `Demo::m2` is the implementation of `It1::m2`,  but `Demo::m1` is not implementing any interface method.

Therefore, when you comment out the declaration of `m1` in `It2`, it makes no difference.

One way to demonstrate this is to add `@Override` annotations:

```
    @Override
    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("m1 method");
    }

    @Override
    public void m2() {
        System.out.println("m2 method");
    }
```

The compiler will give a compilation for the `m1` method saying that it doesn't override or implement anything.  There won't be a compilation error for `m2`.

---

> So, how it's executing process. Is it taking as a default method?

No.  There are no default methods here.